# A Shoe 'in White' / 'in a White' / 'in the White'

Tags: word-usage

I was watching an American sitcom where this exchange took place (between a customer who wants to buy a pair of shoes and a storekeeper, let's assume) :

> *shopkeeper*: Okay. Um, how about these? [Holds out a pair of shoes]
>   *customer*: That's really a day shoe. [...] Could we see something **in a slimmer heel**?
>   *shopkeeper*: [Forages around] Okay, I have nothing **in an evening shoe in the burgundy**. I can show you something **in a silver** that may work.
>   *customer*: No, it really should be burgundy.
>
> *(adapted)*

I have questions about the phrases in bold. I think none of them is fine, and they should be fixed as below:

- *something **in a slimmer heel***  **-->**  *something **with a slimmer heel***
- *I have nothing **in an evening shoe in the burgundy***  **-->** *I have no **evening shoes in burgundy***
- *something **in a silver*** **-->** *something **in silver***

For one thing, you should use no article to express the color of something, as stated *[here (in the 18th definitoin of 'in')](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/in_1)*, in Longman's Dictionary.

After all, I'm not sure. Maybe it's regional usage. So please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Can you tell us the name of the sitcom, and the episode? More information is always better (then people can see the context, intonation and stuff like that if they want to.)

Comment: I think it's more likely to be the sales staff than the customer who would say something like *We have that shoe **in a slimmer heel***, and ***in a silver*** sounds a bit unlikely from either, to my ear. But there aren't really any "rules" governing this, nor do I see much mileage in trying to identify "regional" differences. It's all just a matter of opinion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe you're right, but I failed to understand what you meant by "a matter of opinion". I think based on information like _[this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dress+in+white%2Cdress+in+a+white%2C+dress+in+the+white&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdress%20in%20white%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdress%20in%20a%20white%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdress%20in%20the%20white%3B%2Cc0)_ , we would be able to extract some rules about this usage.

Comment: When you ask for something **in a white**, the implication is that it might be available in various shades of white, say "off white", "cream", "ivory", and so on, and for the time being, you are not specifying the particular sort of white you want.  But suppose the salesperson brings you something in a shade of white you don't care for, you might reasonably say, "Please bring me something in a different white," meaning a different shade of white.  The "a" goes with an understood "shade" or "variety".

Comment: MJF: As @Greg says, the article is perfectly idiomatic in contexts where the speaker knows there are  (or even just *might be*) multiple alternatives within the category (slim heeled, white-ish, etc.). All your NGram tells us is what we should already know (that in *most* contexts this doesn't apply). If you're a native speaker I'd have expected you to know this. If not, you should be asking on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: ...when I said "matter of opinion", I was referring more to the fact that most native speakers would probably be like me, and find ***in a silver*** slightly unusual. But quite possibly the paintsprayer working in a car bodyshop would consider it a perfectly ordinary usage (he might have half-a-dozen different versions of "silver paint").

Comment: I can't explain where it originated, however I suspect it is sales-assistant language right round the English-speaking world. I've heard it since the 1960s in AusE, usually in association with women's clothing and accessories, but also curtains, crockery, cars, and more.  I expect it's affectation employed to sound more formal, more stylish, and more polite (ie, accommodating to the customer's tastes).

Comment: @GregLee Thank you for your comment (which is not a "matter of opinion").

Comment: 'Something in/with a slimmer heel' are both idiomatic. 'I haven't a size 7 in the burgundy' means that there is only one burgundy style being considered. 'I have nothing in an evening shoe in the burgundy' sounds unacceptable to me. 'Something in a silver' implies that the speaker realises that there are different shades (etc) of silver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find the phrasing unusual, at least for American English. But since the question has been neither closed nor answered, allow me to synthesize the comments.

---

Saying *in burgundy* and *in silver* without an article indicates that the speaker has a particular conception of what colors those names represent. But color names can be vague— Wikipedia says all of these are shades of *red*

[image: shades of red]

— and thus *red* is inadequate to describe fashion goods in a consumer society. It's one of the reasons why industry has developed standardized color systems like Pantone, TruMatch, and RAL.

On the flip side, specific color names can also confound because they are chosen for marketing or artistic purposes and not for accuracy or clarity. At this writing, J.Crew will sell you a shirt in *river valley*, Vineyard Vines one in *summer evening*, and Zara in one *nude*— all rather ambiguous (or, perhaps Zara needs to [take a lesson from Crayola](http://www.nytimes.com/1998/02/25/nyregion/crayola-box-of-64-turns-40.html) from half a century ago). Thus, it is natural for an experienced consumer to ask whether something is available in *a silver*, indicating an understanding that there are many possible tones, hues, tints, or shades that could be called *silver*. The shoe might even be available in more than one *silver*, perhaps *wintry stone* on one hand and *city platinum* on the other.

*In the burgundy* in contrast suggests that there is a reference burgundy understood by both the shopper and the clerk, perhaps one seen on display, or known to be offered by this particular manufacturer. Perhaps *burgundy* is used for a narrower range of options than *silver* is. But then, nothing should be more unambiguous than *white*, yet [all kinds of whites](http://www.sherwin-williams.com/homeowners/color/find-and-explore-colors/paint-colors-by-family/family/white-pastel/) are offered.

I read the difference between asking for something *in* instead of *with* a desired slimmer heel as a very slight one: asking whether the shoe is available in an alternative form or expression that contains the feature, as opposed to whether a single instance of the shoe can have that particular feature. I don't think most people would perceive the nuance, but the phrasing is unremarkable in a culture where product [trim levels](http://www.edmunds.com/car-buying/trim-levels-101.html) are very familiar, and you're accustomed to asking if something is available *in* a certain style, size, or other option set.

Comment: Spot-on. Thanks. The indefinite article before 'slimmer' ('in _a_ slimmer heel') would then reflect the fact that there are different styles of slim heel shoes, for example spike heel style or stiletto heel style.